# When is the internal covering number of a metric space monotonic?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces

Given a radius $r > 0$, the internal covering number of a subset $T$ of a metric space $(X, d)$ is denoted $N_r(T)$ and is defined to be the smallest number of balls of radius $r$ (under $d$) with centres in $T$ such that $T$ is contained in the union of the balls.

Given another subset of $X$, $U$, which is a superset of $T$, it is not necessarily true that $N_r(T) \leq N_r(U)$.

My question:

1. Are there well known examples of sets for which $T \subseteq U$ but $N_r(T) > N_r(U)$?
2. Are there necessary/sufficient conditions on $X$ or $d$ such that the internal covering number is monotonic, i.e. $T \subseteq U \implies N_r(T) \leq N_r(U)$?

In case it is relevant, my application is to cases in which $X$ is generated by $T$ under some (infinite) set of transformations (e.g. a Lie group).

Comment: Do you mean balls of a particular radius?  Otherwise the internal covering number of a nonempty bounded set is $1$ and the internal covering number of an unbounded set is $\infty$.

Comment: apologies. yes, I do. Typically you would specify a radius and ask how many balls of that radius are needed to cover a set. I'll update the question.

Comment: An easy example: if $U$ is the Euclidean $n$-dimensional punctured disc of radius $r$, and $T$ the punctured disk, then $N_r(T) = n + 1$ while $N_r(U) = 1$. For general $X$, this idea implies that for any $x \in X, r \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ there is some $x_r$ such that $d(x, y) < r \implies d(x_r, y) < r$ (or $\leq r$, depending on whether you mean the open or closed ball).

Comment: @user44191, a very clean example, nice -- punctured contained if the full (unpunctured) disk. (Your first word "punctured" was a typo).

Comment: Ultrametric spaces satisfy 2. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrametric_space)

Comment: @AntonPetrunin Are ultrametric spaces the _only_ spaces that satisfy 2?

Comment: Yes it seems that only ultrametric spaces satisfy condition 2 --- it sufficient to check 2-point sets in 3-point sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious example: 
Suppose $U$ is a closed ball of radius $1$ in $\mathbb R^d$, and $T$ is the corresponding sphere.  Then if $r = 1$, $N_r(U) = 1$ but $N_r(T) > 1$.

EDIT:
Let $X$ be any metric space such that there are three points $a,b, c$ with $d(a,b) \le d(a,c) < d(b,c)$.  Then take $d(a,c) \le r < d(b,c)$, $T = \{b,c\}$ and $U = \{a,b,c\}$.  We have $N_r(U) = 1$ but $N_r(T) = 2$. 
Asking that this example does not exist is a rather severe restriction on the metric space!

Comment: I think that that restriction is equivalent to the space being ultrametric, as said in the comments to the question. Examples include p-adic spaces.